# Cannot access "tools>Serial port" on Kali Linux

Tags: serial, arduino-ide, linux

I just got my Arduino UNO delivered and I wanted to see if it's working properly or not.

I tried following [this page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Howto) to create a simple program and the program compiled successfully.

But when I tried to select the serial port on IDE, the port option was grayed out. I searched for the problem and I landed on [this page](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ftdi-drivers/linux). It says

> Linux includes the drivers necessary to use Arduino, and no additional
>   install is needed. However, permissions might need to be configured.
>   For current instructions on how to set up these permissions, visit
>   this page.
>
> An alternative method is to run Arduino as root in the terminal.

But I still see the port option grayed out even as a root user. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions in any of the myriad of troubleshooting pages for Linux and Arduino?

Comment: @Majenko: Nope. Not yet. Any suggestion?

Comment: How about doing that thing I just asked if you had done?

Comment: Did you check if Linux created a new device in the /dev directory?  Did you perform a "tail -f" on the log file of your Linux distribution and watched the output as you plugged in your Arduino?  You didn't say which Linux you were using so we can only guess where it keeps it's log file.  BTW, you will probably have to have root permissions to look at the log file.  BTW, you can check on the permissions of new devices at the same time you are checking on what if anything gets created in the /dev directory.

Comment: @st2000 : I'm using Kali Linux and no, plugging in the Arduino doesn't create a new directory in /dev directory. I have the root permission and I tried running Arduino as a root user but the same happens. I do not see any new device/file in /dev.

Comment: Running the application with different permissions will do no good if there is not a device in /dev for the application to connect to.  Plugging in the USB device and creating a serial device in the /dev directory needs to be solved first. Kali is sort of an "attack" version of Debian (older versions were based on Ubuntu, but I'm just going to assume you have a new version of Kali).  So, if they didn't change anything the log file should be at /var/log/syslog.  You can "tail -f /var/log/syslog" and watch while you plug in your USB device and see what is happening.